# Android View Visibility and Performance

Tags: android, performance, android-espresso

I am using Espresso to test an Android application. Because there is no easy way to get and examine the text from a WebView I have to get creative. My solution is to store the HTML of a WebView in a TextView and use the android:visibility="invisible" attribute.

Then I can grab the text associated with the view ID in Espresso to see if it contains expected values.

The size of the HTML isn’t that large (less than 10kb). Seeing as our application uses several WebViews I have to this a few times on a screen (say like 5, so it will be 50kb character max). We are wondering if there anyone knows of any sizeable performance implications in doing this?

Any opinions or comments on this will be appreciated.

Thanks
-Andrew